# Performance issues with angular 4 and PrimeNG datagrid

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG datagrid for angular 4, in the grid I have 18 columns and for now there are maximum 50 rows which can seen at once with pagination. My requirement is to show 100 and 150 rows per page as well, but beyond 50, the grid is giving serious performance issues, like the rendering takes around 30 seconds and it takes more 10 seconds to become usable, data is loaded from the server, and the data received from the server is quite fast.

Has anyone else faced problem. If yes, how were you able to fix the same.

**HTML**

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="autoProcessGridData" [(selection)]="selectedRows" [(rows)]="rowsCountPerPage" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event,false,'')"
    [(totalRecords)]="totalRecords" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"
    [sortField]="fields.TIMEINPROCESSING.field" sortOrder="1" sortOrder="1" scrollable="true" [scrollHeight]="viewHeight">
          <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols; let i = index" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [(hidden)]="col.hidden" [styleClass]="col.class" [style]="{'display' : (col.hidden?'none':'')}" selectionMode="{{col.header==fields.BULKACTIONS.header ? 'multiple': ''}}"
              [sortable]="col.sortable">
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.TIMEINPROCESSING.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                      <span [ngClass]="getClass(row[fields.TIMEINPROCCODE.field])">{{row[fields.TIMEINPROCESSING.field]}}</span>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.ACTIONS.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right iconstyle {{isEnabled(row, 'sendtomanual')? 'sendtomanual' : 'disabled-icon'}}" (click)="openSingleRowTaskModel(row, 'SENDTOMANUAL')" title="Send To Manual"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-refresh iconstyle {{isEnabled(row, 'requeue')? 'requeue' : 'disabled-icon'}}" (click)="openSingleRowTaskModel(row,'REQUEUE')" title="Requeue File"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-close iconstyle {{isEnabled(row, 'reject')? 'reject' : 'disabled-icon'}}" (click)="openSingleRowTaskModel(row,'REJECT')" title="Reject File"></span>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.field==fields.INDEX.field" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                      <span title="{{row[fields.INDEX.field]}}">{{row[fields.INDEX.field]}}</span>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.BULKACTIONS.header" pTemplate="header">
                      <span [popover]="myPopoverAuto" popoverPlacement="auto bottom" class="fa fa-cog cog-icon pull-right" title="View Bulk Action"></span>
                      <span style="width:80%">{{col.header}}</span>
                          <popover-content #myPopoverAuto placement="right" [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
                          <h3>Bulk Action</h3>
                          <p>
                                                            {{selectedRows.length ? selectedRows.length : 0}} items selected
                          </p>
                          <ul>
                              <li>
                                 <span (click)="myPopoverAuto.hide(); openBulkTaskModel('SENDTOMANUAL')"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right iconstyle sendtomanual"></em> Send To Manual</span>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <span (click)="myPopoverAuto.hide(); openBulkTaskModel('REQUEUE')"><em class="fa fa-refresh iconstyle requeue"></em> Requeue Files</span>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <span (click)="myPopoverAuto.hide(); openBulkTaskModel('REJECT')"><em class="fa fa-close iconstyle reject"></em> Reject to Client</span>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </popover-content>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.DATACENTER.header" pTemplate="header" let-col>
                      <span>{{col.header}}</span>
                          <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="defaultDataCenter" [options]="dataCentreDd" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" (onChange)="filterByField($event, col.field, fieldType.DD);"
                                                    styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template *ngIf="col.filter==true" pTemplate="header">
                                            <span>{{col.header}}
                       <span *ngIf="isDisabled(i) && col.dualFilter==true" title="Clear Filter" class="clearFunnel fa fa-close" (click)="enableTextFilter(i, col.field)"></span>
                                                    <em *ngIf="col.dualFilter==true" class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true" (click)="getFilterOnClick($event,col.field,i)"></em>
                      <p-multiSelectFilter *ngIf="col.dualFilter==true" 
                                                    [options]="funnelFilterOptions" 
                                                    [value]=customfilterValues[col.field] 
                                                    (onApply)="applyFunnelFilter($event)"
                                                    (onSelfClick)="onSelfClickFunnel($event)" 
                                                    [field]="col.field"
                                                    [filterTitle]="col.header">
                  </p-multiSelectFilter>
                  </span>
                  <input [(ngModel)]="filters[i]" type="text" size="30" pInputText (keyup)="filterByField($event, col.field, fieldType.TEXT, i)"
                                            (focus)="old[i]=filters[i]; doManualScroll(col.field)"  (blur)="changeEvent(old[i], filters[i], col.field)"
                                                    class="{{'input-'+col.field}}" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled(i) ? true : null" />
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.PROCESSEDBYFIRSTNAME.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                  <span *ngIf="row[fields.PROCESSEDBYFIRSTNAME.field] != null">{{row[fields.PROCESSEDBYFIRSTNAME.field]}} {{row[fields.PROCESSEDBYLASTNAME.field]}}</span>
                  <span *ngIf="row[fields.PROCESSEDBYFIRSTNAME.field] == null">N/A</span>
             </ng-template>
             <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.UPLOADEDBYFIRSTNAME.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                 <span *ngIf="row[fields.UPLOADEDBYFIRSTNAME.field] != null">{{row[fields.UPLOADEDBYFIRSTNAME.field]}} {{row[fields.UPLOADEDBYLASTNAME.field]}}</span>
                 <span *ngIf="row[fields.UPLOADEDBYFIRSTNAME.field] == null">N/A</span>
             </ng-template>
             <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.LASTACTION.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                 <span *ngIf="row[fields.LASTACTION.field] != null">{{row[fields.LASTACTION.field]}}</span>
                 <span *ngIf="row[fields.LASTACTION.field] == null">N/A</span>
            </ng-template>
           <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.LASTACTIONDATE.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
              <span *ngIf="row[fields.LASTACTIONDATE.field] != null">{{localDate(row[fields.LASTACTIONDATE.field])}}</span>
                  <span *ngIf="row[fields.LASTACTIONDATE.field] == null">N/A</span>
           </ng-template>
           <ng-template *ngIf="col.header==fields.PROJECT.header" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
               <span><a class="reject" (click)="openProjectModel(row)">{{row[fields.PROJECT.field]}} </a> </span>
           </ng-template>
       </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Will you please edit the question and add the code that you have done?

Comment: @The Dictator I have added the html, let me know, if I need to add anything else

Comment: There's a lot of code there. Can you remove columns until you see if there's a problematic column? Then maybe post the code for `isEnabled` and `isDisabled`

Comment: @Hayden I have tried all that, it is not making much difference

Comment: You need lazy loading with this? Can't you just use Simple paging?

Comment: @TheDictator lazy loading is required to load data from server

Comment: I had the same issue with editable columns. Updated to the latest version of primeNg (5.0.2); performance better than before

Comment: @Amit Is it possible to run primeng(5.0.2) with angular(4.2.3)

Comment: @SahilAgarwal No. See here. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-0-0-released/

Comment: may I suggest my datagrid library [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid). Slickgrid is the fastest jQuery library and I wrapped it to work with Angular 4+ and added a bunch of features